# remove date, title, number of comments from homepage wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I am converting a html theme to wordpress theme. I have created header.php, footer.php, style.css, sidebar.php

After that I have added a post in admin panel and called in homepage. I am getting the post content in home page, but along with that I am also getting title, date, post by admin, number of comments all these stuff. I didnt create funcitons.php till now. I want to remove all those and display only content. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you editing an existing theme? Or using s child theme? It sounds like there is some templates being loaded in which will need modifying

Comment: I am not using existing theme and I am not using child theme. I have created theme files like header.php, footer.php, style.css, sidebar.php and uploaded to the wordpress.

Comment: Ok cool, so you're setting the homepage in the Wordpress settings to display a Wordpress page you have created in Wordpress? If this is the case the title etc should be in the index.php file or the page.php file, do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: Yeah Sure...

Below is the index.php code. I didnt create any funcions.php or page.php code in my theme.

<!-- Welcome Content Starts Here 
  ==============================================-->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to add the code in proper way... It is not allowing to format the code..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.entry-title, .entry-date, .comments {display: none;}
```